# Why is my content not displaying after the page gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello i have created a loading screen for my home page, but the content doesn't display after the site has loaded. I set the console log to send message once it has loaded and I don't get any errors. Does anyone know why this is happening? Also, how can I get the loading text to fade every time it changes as well?

```js
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  function loadingScreen() {
    var loadingText = document.getElementById('loading-text');
    loadingText.innerText = "Welcome To StudioPick."
    var delay = 7000;
    return timeout(delay)
      .then(() => { loadingText.innerText = "Loading studios..."; return timeout(delay) })
      .then(() => { loadingText.innerText = "Almost done..."; return timeout(delay) })
      .then(() => { loadingText.innerText = "Let's get started"; return timeout(delay) })
      .then(() => { loadingText.parentElement.style.display = "none" })
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log("content has loaded.")
    loadingScreen();
  });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

body {
  background-color: #d1d1d1 !important;
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#loading-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 33rem;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#loading {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #9370db url(/dist/512x512\ Half\ Circle.gif);
  background-size: 2%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 5;
}

.navbar-nav {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.nav-item2 {
  background-color: #9370db !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  width: 95px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 75vh;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

header .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Media Query for devices withi coarse pointers and no hover functionality */

/* This will use a fallback image instead of a video for devices that commonly do not support the HTML5 video element */

@media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
  header {
    background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/XT5OInaElMw/1600x900") black
      no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
  header video {
    display: none;
  }
}

.graybg {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.searchbox {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -130px;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  right: -185px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.zipcode {
  position: relative;
  right: -165px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.sortbox {
  position: relative;
  right: -75px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 33%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.filterbox {
  position: relative;
  right: 85px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.enter-site {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  right: -580px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 25;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  top: 225px;
  z-index: 20;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/*---Header---*/
.sturow > * {
  flex: 1;
}
/*---Studio List---*/
.stucontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

/*---Card One---*/

/*---Star Rating 1---*/
.rating-box {
  width: 175px;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  height: 35px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

/* hide radio buttons */

input[name="star"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

/* hide source svg */

.star-source {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* set initial color to transparent so fill is empty*/

.star {
  color: #7a7a7a;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* set direction to row-reverse so 5th star is at the end and ~ can be used to fill all sibling stars that precede last starred element*/

.star-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

label:hover ~ label .star,
svg.star:hover,
input[name="star"]:focus ~ label .star,
input[name="star"]:checked ~ label .star {
  color: #fbff28;
}

input[name="star"]:checked + label .star {
  animation: starred 0.5s;
}

input[name="star"]:checked + label {
  animation: scaleup 1s;
}

@keyframes scaleup {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes starred {
  from {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
  to {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
}

/*---Links---*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}

/*---Card Body---*/

.card1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 420px;
  height: 330px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card1 .card-meta {
  position: relative;
  right: -55px;
  color: #9370db;
}

.stuLocation {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  right: -55px;
}
/*---Like Button---*/

.btns1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
}

.card1.card-has-bg {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  background-size: 130%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.card1.card-has-bg:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-size: 130%;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1.card-has-bg:hover .card-img-overlay {
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #d2d2d25c 100%);
}

.card1 .card-body {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1:hover .card-body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1 .card-img-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.425);
}

/*---Card Body---*/

/*---Heart Button---*/

.btns1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  left: 300px;
}

/*---Heart Button---*/

/*---Star Rating---*/

.rating-box {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: -105px;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  width: 105px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #e5e5e55a;
  border: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

/* hide radio buttons */

input[name="star"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

/* hide source svg */

.star-source {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* set initial color to transparent so fill is empty*/

.star {
  color: #7a7a7a;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* set direction to row-reverse so 5th star is at the end and ~ can be used to fill all sibling stars that precede last starred element*/

.star-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

label:hover ~ label .star,
svg.star:hover,
input[name="star"]:focus ~ label .star,
input[name="star"]:checked ~ label .star {
  color: #fbff28;
}

input[name="star"]:checked + label .star {
  animation: starred 0.5s;
}

input[name="star"]:checked + label {
  animation: scaleup 1s;
}

@keyframes scaleup {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes starred {
  from {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
  to {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
}

/*---Star Rating---*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 350px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}

/*---Card stack---*/

.stucontainer .card1-stack {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .buttons {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  top: 55%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .buttons:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .prev {
  left: 15px;
  right: auto;
}

.container .card1-stack .next {
  left: auto;
  right: 15px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .carousel .buttons:hover {
  color: #c01313;
  background: #fff;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list {
  width: 300px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list__image {
  height: 200px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list__text {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 24px;
  width: 60%;
  /* animation: scaleCard 100ms; */
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 36px;
  width: 70%;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 48px;
  width: 80%;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 60px;
  width: 90%;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(5) {
  top: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .card1-stack:hover > .buttons.prev {
  display: block;
  animation: bounceInLeft 200ms;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack:hover > .buttons.next {
  display: block;
  animation: bounceInRight 200ms;
}

.transformThis {
  animation: scaleDown 500ms;
}

.transformPrev {
  animation: scaleUp 100ms;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(30px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.01) translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleDown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.01) translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(60px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(80px);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleCard {
  0% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 24px;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

/*---Card stack---*/

/*---Card One---*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.98.0">
    <title>StudioPick</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <div id="loading">
        <div id="loading-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="page">

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand"
                        href="#"><strong>StudioPick</strong></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" style="color: #ffffff;"
                                    href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" style="color: #ffffff;" href="login.html"><strong>Log In</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item2">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="signup.html"><strong>Sign Up</strong></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- This div is  intentionally blank. It creates the transparent black overlay over the video which you can modify in the CSS -->
            <div class="overlay"></div>

            <!-- The HTML5 video element that will create the background video on the header -->
            <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
                <source src="./Joony_Vlog.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

            <!-- The header content -->
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="w-100">
                        <div class="searchbox">
                            <h1 style="font-size: 50px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"><strong>Find Your Next
                                    Studio</strong></h1>

                            <div class="row">
                                <!---Search--->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                                </div>

                                <!---Zipcode-->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input class="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode">
                                </div>

                                <!---Sort----->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="sortbox">
                                        <option value="Sort">Sort by</option>
                                        <option value="Location">Location</option>
                                        <option value="Rating">Rating</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <!---Filter--->

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="filterbox">
                                        <option value="Filter">Filter</option>
                                        <option value="50 mi">50 mi</option>
                                        <option value="30 mi">30 mi</option>
                                        <option value="25 mi">25 mi</option>
                                        <option value="10 mi">10 mi</option>
                                        <option value="5 mi">5 mi</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <button class="enter-site" onclick="window.location.href='Index.html'"></a><strong>View
                                        Studios</strong></button>

                                <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50" id="footer">
                                    <p>@Bekaedo <br>StudioPick 2022 ©</p>
                                </footer>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Page section example for content below the video header -->
        <section class="my-5">
            <div class="container">
                <!--Studio List-->
                <div class="row">
                    <!--Studio One-->
                    <div class="stuOne mx-auto">
                        <div class="stucontainer">
                            <div class="card1-stack">
                                <!--Studio Front Page-->
                                <li class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col"
                                    style="background-image:url('https://westlakepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SnoopDoggStudio.jpg');">
                                    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="media">
                                                <img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" id="stuImage"
                                                    src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxUXsEFPioqCqDqgp7MeLNpM7iZYL6mt97ElI3LwCnuFoarwmSWbJquoEwbi1AJSRzXBs&usqp=CAU"
                                                    alt="Generic placeholder image"
                                                    style="max-width:50px; position: relative; top: 50px; left: -150px;">
                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                    <h6 class="card-meta mb-2"><strong>CC Studios</strong></h6>
                                                    <small class="stuLocation">Bethesda, MD</small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--Heart Button--->
                                            <div class="btns1">
                                                <Button style="font-size: 35px" onclick="Toggle1()" id="btnh1"
                                                    class="btn"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></Button>
                                            </div>
                                            <!---Heart Button--->
                                            <!---Star Rating--->
                                            <div class="rating-box">
                                                <div class="star-source">
                                                    <svg>
                                                        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="5.41294643%" x2="87.5527344%"
                                                            y2="65.4921875%" id="grad">
                                                            <stop stop-color="#bf209f" offset="0%"></stop>
                                                            <stop stop-color="#d62a9d" offset="60%"></stop>
                                                            <stop stop-color="#ED009E" offset="100%"></stop>
                                                        </linearGradient>
                                                        <symbol id="star" viewBox="153 89 106 108">
                                                            <polygon id="star-shape" stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="5"
                                                                fill="currentColor"
                                                                points="206 162.5 176.610737 185.45085 189.356511 150.407797 158.447174 129.54915 195.713758 130.842203 206 95 216.286242 130.842203 253.552826 129.54915 222.643489 150.407797 235.389263 185.45085">
                                                            </polygon>
                                                        </symbol>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="star-container">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="star" id="five">
                                                    <label for="five">
                                                        <svg class="star">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="star" id="four">
                                                    <label for="four">
                                                        <svg class="star">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="star" id="three">
                                                    <label for="three">
                                                        <svg class="star">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="star" id="two">
                                                    <label for="two">
                                                        <svg class="star">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="star" id="one">
                                                    <label for="one">
                                                        <svg class="star">
                                                            <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!---Star Rating--->


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Studio Front Page-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Studio One-->

                    <!--Studio Two-->

                    <!--Studio Two-->



                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>





    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is just a string. Setting a property like `fadeOut` on it does nothing

Comment: There is no value for `display` called `visible`, only `none`, `block`, `inline`, `flex`, `grid`, etc.

Comment: ohh ok, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `display: none` to `.loading-text`, it needs to be set on its parent (`#loading`).

As for fading, `innerText.fadeOut` does nothing. I would suggest doing this with css by toggling appropriate classes with js.

Comment: This worked, but now the screen isn't performing the loading screen

Comment: In my test it works fine. I used `loadingText.parentElement.style.display = 'none'`. You can share the updated code. Maybe I could spot the problem

Comment: one last thing sorry lol, is the content showing up on your side when you scroll to the bottom while loading screen is running?

Comment: Loading screen disappears and content shows up on time whether I scroll or not

Comment: I can see the bottom of screen on my end. I updated my code to show what I currently have

Comment: I see what you mean now. Use position `fixed` instead of `absolute` on the loading div.